# Choosing default boot sequence

Tags: gnome, login, default

I choose working version from grub menu and run boot repair which says:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6457971/

I want to know how can I make it my default boot sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you choose in boot repair is what you will have installed in your booting sequence..just don't forget so save settings and update all configuration changes that you desired to make and then restart.

You can preview everything from inside the super boot manager.